# REGEX match x times "<li> anything in here </li>"

Tags: regex

I have a string like this in PHP

```
<li>bla bla bla bla</li>
<li>hello hello</li>
<li>the brown fox didnt jump</li>
.
.
.
<li>aaaaaaarghhhh</li>
```

I want to get a string wich contains the first X li's  (li tags included in the result string)

```
<li>.....first one....</li>
<li>.....second one....</li>
<li>.................</li>
<li>.....X one....</li>
```

How can this be done with REGEX or something else????

I could remove the

```
</li>
```

then explode by

```
<li>
```

and get the first X elements of array and then adding again li tags at beginning and at end of each element, but i think its too dirty...

Any better ideas?

Comment: Famous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: i don't ask for a complete HTML parser, this is a string without any other HTML tags except for <li> and </li>. I want to match X times a string that starts with <li> and ending with </li>. If you dont like li's replace <li> with "Dogs" and </li> with "Cats".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this regex works for you (replace the number 2 with the required number of li):

```
((?:<li>.*?<\/li>){2})
```

Comment: A little modified version for to get it work with the example provided: `/^(?:<li>.*?</li>\s*){2}/`

Answer (score 2):

How about parsing it as actual DOM elements using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

You can download the script from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

If you load that script in to your current script like this:

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
$html = "<li>bla bla bla bla</li>, etc, etc ......";

$list_array = array();

foreach($html->find('li') as $element) {
    $list_array[] = $element->innertext;
}
```