# Regex to match first two <li> of a <ul> list

Tags: javascript, html, regex

We have a HTML string where we have a list. Something like shown below

```
<ul><li>Item A</li><li>Item B</li><li>Item C</li><li>Item D</li></ul>
```

Here is the formatted version of the same.

```
<ul>
   <li>Item A</li>
   <li>Item B</li>
   <li>Item C</li>
   <li>Item D</li>
</ul>
```

My objective is to write a regular expression to select the first two items for the list. So the output should be

```
<ul>
   <li>Item A</li>
   <li>Item B</li>
</ul>
```

If that's not possible to do it in regex, what will be a most optimized way to do it through plain javascript code.

Comment: I think this should help answered here: [REGEX match x times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731359/regex-match-x-times-li-anything-in-here-li)

Comment: What should the result of this be? An HTML string or an actual element / document fragment?

Comment: @Phil It should be string with <ul> and match <li>s

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regex for this. [Parse the HTML into a document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) and use DOM methods to remove the elements

```js
const html = `<ul><li>Item A</li><li>Item B</li><li>Item C</li><li>Item D</li></ul>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

// Remove all <li> elements after the 2nd
doc.querySelectorAll("li:nth-child(n+3)").forEach(el => el.remove());

// DOMParser puts the HTML fragment into the created document body
const newHtml = doc.body.innerHTML;

console.log(newHtml);
```

This also works with end-tag omission like this...

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item A
   <li>Item B
   <li>Item C
   <li>Item D
</ul>
```

which is potentially something a regular expression could really struggle with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const str = `<ul><li>Item A</li><li>Item B</li><li>Item C</li><li>Item D</li></ul>`
const re = tag => new RegExp(`<${tag}>(.*?)<\/${tag}>`, 'g')
const ul = str.replace(re('ul'), ($1, $2) =>
  $1.replace($2, $2.match(re('li')).slice(0, 2).join(``)))

console.log(ul)
```